Error al agregar varias rows a tabla con apose.words
Hola comunidad perdonen estoy presentando un error, por lo cual pido de su apoyo, no se si sea por tema de la logica como tal o no estoy usando bien el paquete apose.words esto es en c# api
//Aqui obtengo la plantilla y la cargo con Document (Apose) esta plantilla internamente tiene 2 tablas 
plantillaWord = new Document(stream);

//Obtengo la ultima tabla
var tabla = (Table)plantillaWord.GetChildNodes(NodeType.Table, true).Last();

//Saco la ultima Row de dicha tabla es decir excluyo los cabeceros
Row CopiaRow = (Row)tabla.LastRow.Clone(true);

//Ya teniendo la Row de la tabla que quiero voy a insertar datos y row en esa misma tabla tantas veces me lo indique una lista que me mandan entonces hago un foreach a la lista y sustituyo los valores


foreach (var datos in listaRow)
{
  table.Rows[2].ParentNode.InsertAfter(clonedRow, table.Rows[2]); //lei que con este codigo inserta la row que sacaste al finale de la tabla 
  plantillaWord .Range.Replace(parametroRow, datos.value); //aqui en suplanto info de la row con datos
  
}

Esto es funcional cuando tengo solo 2 item en la lista pero cuando tengo mas marca el error
Cannot add a node before/after itself no entiendo por que pasa al 3er item si la row limpia la saco antes del foreach y al entrar voy insertando esa misma row limpia
